# Name Error and other?

Tags: python

Basically I'm learning Python right now so I'm just using other people's templates and just editing them. So far, I've learned that indention in Python is very picky.
However I'm stuck, I think I have everything indented correctly and definedright, but I'm still getting this error in my console. (windows)

(And yes, I know it's not done yet)

```
"...\documents\python_files>python calc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc.py", line 20, in <module>
    class Calculator(wx.Dialog):
  File "calc.py", line 46, in Calculator
    b = wx.Button(self, -1, label)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined"
```

Here is my code (I *think* I put it here in code format):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division

__author__ = 'Sean'
__version__ = '0.0.2'

#Calculator GUI:

# ____________v
#[(][)][^][log]
#[C][±][√][%]
#[7][8][9][/]
#[4][5][6][*]
#[1][2][3][-]
#[0][.][+][=]

import wx
from math import *

class Calculator(wx.Dialog):
    '''Main calculator dialog'''
    def __init__(self):
        title = 'Calculator version %s' % __version__
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, title)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # Main vertical sizer

        # ____________v
        self.display = wx.ComboBox(self, -1)
        sizer.Add(self.display, 0, wx.EXPAND)


    #[(][)][^][log]
    #[C][±][√][%]
    #[7][8][9][/]
    #[4][5][6][*]
    #[1][2][3][-]
    #[0][.][+][=]
    gsizer = wx.GridSizer(4,6)
    for row in (("(",")","^","log"),
    ("C","±","√","%"),
    ("7", "8", "9", "/"),
    ("4", "5", "6", "*"),
    ("1", "2", "3", "-"),
    ("0", ".", "+", "=")):
        for label in row:
            b = wx.Button(self, -1, label)
            gsizer.Add(b)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_Button,self.OnButton, b)
            sizer.Add(gsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    b = wx.Button(self, -1, "=")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, b)
    sizer.Add(b, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.equal = b

    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    sizer.Fit(self)
    self.CenterOnScreen()

def OnButton(self, evt):
    '''Handle button click event'''
    label = evt.GetEventObject().GetLabel()

    if label == '=':
        try:
            compute = self.display.GetValue()
            if not compute.strip():
                return

            result = eval(compute)

            self.display.Insert(compute, 0)

            self.display.SetValue(str(result))
        except Exception as err:
            wx.LogError(str(err))
            return

    elif label == 'C':
        self.display.SetValue('')

    else:
        self.display.SetValue(self.display.GetValue() + label)
        self.equal.SetFocus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    dlg = Calculator()
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation for part of the `__init__` method is wrong:

```
class Calculator(wx.Dialog):
    '''Main calculator dialog'''
    def __init__(self):
        title = 'Calculator version %s' % __version__
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, title)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # Main vertical sizer
        self.display = wx.ComboBox(self, -1)
        sizer.Add(self.display, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        # This part was indented wrong
        gsizer = wx.GridSizer(4,6)
        for row in (("(",")","^","log"),
                    ("C","±","√","%"),
                    ("7", "8", "9", "/"),
                    ("4", "5", "6", "*"),
                    ("1", "2", "3", "-"),
                    ("0", ".", "+", "=")):
        for label in row:
            b = wx.Button(self, -1, label)
            gsizer.Add(b)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_Button,self.OnButton, b)
            sizer.Add(gsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        b = wx.Button(self, -1, "=")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, b)
        sizer.Add(b, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.equal = b
```

You should read up on Python. From the [Python 2 tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html):

> Note that each line within a basic block must be indented by the same amount.

Another thing to read is the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: It's generally best to get a book and read it. An editor wouldn't help them, since there's no syntax error - it's ok to have code in the class body.

Comment: Thanks for that, and I should also read the tutorial because editing things has brought me to a dead end.

Comment: Another good read is the Python Style Guide (see updated answer). If this answer is correct to you, please click the checkmark in front of it to mark it as such.